# Im getting Listen EACCES on my nodejs app

Tags: linux, node.js

Im new in linux, so I got a aws amazon server and install nodejs and mongodb in var/www/html .

Dir:

```
-var
 -www
  -html
   -server.js
   -public
   -node_modules
    -express
    -mongodb
    -mongoose
```

In my server.js:

```
  var express = require('express');
  var app = express();
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
  app.listen(8080);
```

When I run:

```
   $ node server
```

I get this error:

```
  Error: listen EADDRINUSE
   at errnoException (net.js:905:11)
   at Server._listen2 (net.js:1043:14)
   at listen (net.js:1065:10)
   at Server.listen (net.js:1139:5)
   at EventEmitter.listen (/var/www/html/node_modules/express/lib/application.j s:617:24)
```

My app is running in port 8080.But I cant run mongosee with this error. Can u help me guys?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the port 8080 is already in use. Try to set different port to your program temporarily:

```
app.listen(8085);
```

If the problem disappear you need to find which program is using port `8080`. You can use `netstat -tulpn` for such task.

Comment: Hi, I would like to use 8080 because my website runs on 8080 only. So, I just changed to 8085 to test and the problem is gone. When I did netstat -tulpn , I got this: tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080                0.0.0.0:*                   LIST

Comment: How can I do it to run on 8080?

Comment: To run your program on 8080 you need to stop the program which already use 8080.  To know the program which use 8080 you need to use `netstat -tulpn`.  Last column on the output is program name: `tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:34435         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      13718/firefox`. Looks like you post not all output.

Comment: Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -

Comment: It does not show the programa, instead of it shows "-"

Comment: Try to use `fuser 8080/tcp`

Comment: And `lsof -i:8080`

Comment: COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
node    2482 root   10u  IPv4  10376      0t0  TCP *:webcache (LISTEN)

Comment: Well, `node` is a program name. `2482` is a process ID.  You can kill it using `kill -9 2482`

Comment: I tried to kill it before, but when I kill, another opens node    2745 root   10u  IPv4  11977      0t0  TCP *:webcache (LISTEN)
I set one file on init.d to initialize it when server start, i dont know if it is causing this issue